# can't use read on interrupt handler - termios

Tags: c, arduino, uart, termios

I am trying to connect a raspberry and an arduino-like(crius aio) device over serial. Crius writes 5 bytes every one second(8bits per transfer,115200 baudrate,1 stop bit,no parity bit,LSB sent first,non inverted bytes) and I can see them on my logical analyzer so I am sure that bytes are sent correctly. So I am trying to read those bytes to raspberry using termios.

```
int serialport_init(const char* serialport)
{
    fd = open(serialport, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open ttyAMA0\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    saio.sa_restorer = NULL; 
    sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

    tcgetattr(fd,&termAttr);

    termAttr.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    termAttr.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    termAttr.c_oflag = 0;
    termAttr.c_lflag = ICANON;   //Input mode=canonical + no echo (wait for CR)

    termAttr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;      //Inter-char timer.   
    termAttr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1 ;      //Block until n bytes are received

    //May not work (GNU/Linux 2.6.35)
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termAttr) == -1)
    {
        printf("termAttr ERROR\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("UART1 configured....\n");

    usleep(2000000); //delay 2 seconds and then return

    return 0;
}

void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
    static uint8_t b = 0;
    if(read(fd, &b, 1)>0)
        printf("received data from UART...: %d\n", b);
    b++;

}
```

When I comment the if statement on signal handler my code works fine. When I uncomment that line my code stops after printing "UART1 configured...."
Any hints?

Comment: Your filedescriptor fd is declared as non-blocking (O_NONBLOCK) that means, you might want to wait for something to read before you actually call read. Have you tried to use a blocking file descriptor (simply remove O_NONBLOCK)?

Comment: I don't get why I have to make my fd on non-blocking. The read is in a signal handler designed exactly for that purpose!

Comment: From what do you conclude you had to make "*fd on non-blocking*"?

Comment: Don't call `printf()` from a signal handler.  It's not async-signal-safe.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html:  "A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing
       elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution
       of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a
       signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler
       calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is
       undefined."

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Henle. I forgot, I will try that.... even though I don't get why when I remove the if statement my handler works with printf....

Comment: Any reason you need to do this with `SIGIO`?  Why can't you just allow `read()` to block in your main thread, like usual? Or, if you have multiple fds you care about, use `select` or `poll` to mux them all into a single thread?

Comment: I want to do this using Interrupts because I need to do something else and just sync the two devices data. @AndrewHenle that didn't work...

Comment: For debugging purpose you want to log the value `read()` returns. Testing for error you should do anyways.

Comment: I am! When I uncomment read, my program stops there...When I comment it the program works...

Comment: If read is blocking, the fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY) is not working.  That may be because the fd is opened with non-blocking.  That means that "open " returns immediately, not waiting for the device to be ready.  In short, the device may not have been ready when "fcntl" was called. Check the return value.

Comment: *"I want to do this using Interrupts"* -- It's the device driver that should be using interrupts.  Calling **read()** from a signal handler isn't going to speed up I/O; **read()** only moves data from a system buffer to the user buffer.  Also specifying **ICANON** with **VMIN** and **VTIME** is nonsensical; **VMIN** and **VTIME** only work in raw mode and ignored in non-blocking mode.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Sys](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response!! I ended up using pthreads and polling... I really wanted to use interrupts because the other device is a dedicated multicopter pilot and I wanted fast responses....